# Use argument from the console JAVA

Tags: java, console

i want to use arguments from console in ubuntu

> ./myTool -ip 1.2.3.4

how can i tack\use the 1.2.3.4 in my code that

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{


    for(int i=0;i<argv.length;i++)
    {
        if (argv[i].equals("-ip"))
        {

         ping(80,"The ip that i want(1.2.3.4)")
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more generic approach to parsing the cmdline arguments I would recommend using one of the already existing frameworks - they do all the heavy lifting for you.

Take a look at [JOpt Simple](http://pholser.github.io/jopt-simple/) - this one is used by eg. OpenJDK.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{
    for(int i=0;i<argv.length;i++)
    {
        if (argv[i].equals("-ip") && argv.length > i+1)
        {
            ping(80, argv[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you implemented `ping`, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You could either encapsulate the behavior you need into an object of your own design or use one that already exists, like [this one](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) from Apache.

You have to be sure that they appear in pairs.  Something like this:

```
public static Map<String, String> getArgsMap(String [] args) { 
    Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if ((args != null) && (args.length > 1) && (args.length % 2) == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
            pairs.put(args[i], args[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```